# Program don´t want to compare the values

Tags: python

First time I put something here, sorry if I did any mistake.

My program use two boundary limits to force the my program to stay in array, but he fails to compare the limits, and I don´t find the problem.

Limits:
    pos_range = [-1.2, 0.60]
    vel_range = [-0.07, 0.07]

The velocity and position update are below, after the update of values I check the results because the car can not go over the pos_range or vel_range, BUT he always goes. Do I did any mistakes to compare the value?  This method is wrong ?

thanks.

```
pos_range = [-1.2, 0.60]
vel_range = [-0.07, 0.07]

def update_position_velocity(a):
    # action 0,1,2,3 0 backward 1 forward 2 coast
    global simulatev
    global simulatep
    global newv
    global newp
    oldv = simulatev  # preserve old values
    oldp = simulatep

    if a == 0:  # backward
        aval = -1
    else:
        aval = a  # coast = 0, forward = +1, backward = -1;

    newv = oldv + (0.001 * aval) + (gravity * cos(3 * oldp))  # update equation for velocity

    newp = simulatep + newv  # update equation for position
    print newp, newv

    if newv < vel_range[0]:  # clip velocity if necessary to keep it within range
        newv = vel_range[0]

    if newv > vel_range[1]:
        newv = vel_range[1]

    if newp < pos_range[0]:  # clip position and velocity if necessary to keep it within range
        newp = pos_range[0]
        newv = 0  # reduce velocity to 0 if position was out of bounds

    if newv > pos_range[1]:
        newp = pos_range[1]
        newv = 0

    print newp, newv
    simulatep = newp
    simulatev = newv  # update state to new values
```

The program fails here:

```
if newv < vel_range[0]:  # clip velocity if necessary to keep it within range
    newv = vel_range[0]

if newv > vel_range[1]:
    newv = vel_range[1]

if newp < pos_range[0]:  # clip position and velocity if necessary to keep it within range
    newp = pos_range[0]
    newv = 0  # reduce velocity to 0 if position was out of bounds

if newv > pos_range[1]:
    newp = pos_range[1]
    newv = 0
```

Comment: Pretty good first post. But, tell me, what is the actual error message that you get, and with what line?

Comment: where are ```vel_range``` and ```pos_range``` defined in the code?

Comment: In what way does the program fail?

Comment: I see a typo: `if newv > pos_range[1]` probably should read `if newp > pos_range[1]`.  That might not be your only problem, but without a complete program that I can run for myself I don't think I can be any more help.

Comment: @JohnColeman How can you assume that the entire snippet's scope is within `update_position_velocity`?

Comment: @KevinOrr It seemed to make more sense that way. In any event, OP is welcome to roll back the edit if I am mistaken. Nothing *calls* `update_position_velocity`, so it would be disconnected from the rest of the program if the scope isn't all of the posted code.

Comment: @JohnColeman fair enough

Comment: Also, your selection of values for `a` and `aval` seem to be inconsistent with the comments, and another possible source of error. For instance, if you pass `2` (for coast), it seems the car will accelerate more rapidly then if you pass `1` (for forward)

Comment: thanks very much @zwol !

Comment: @JohnColeman doesn't say there is an error, just that it doesn't work. As far as I can tell, the problem is that the car doesn't stay within the range required